# Attach txt file and send to bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

How i can send the txt file that i created with the **FileOutputStream** trought of **screemShare**

i can also not found the file path

```
//x = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() +"/pec.txt";
```

this is my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(x);         

        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "PEC");

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Imprimir"));
```

Comment: /data cannot be accessed without root

Comment: The app specific  data folders can be accessed by the  specific app. But not to external apps. So better save your file to external memory.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check this example that work for me [HERE](http://java.dzone.com/articles/bluetooth-data-transfer)

Comment: How i can do that? give me a example please

Comment: LOL @abh22ishek Do you read?


intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

intent.setType("text/plain");

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file_to_transfer) ); maybe you need to read....

Comment: @RicardoFagmer i don't need to use internal bluetooth via intent. otherwise its simple